# How can I save myself after falling for an alarm scam?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, scams

Last week my wife let in an alarm salesman that she had spoken to earlier in the day and asked me to sit down with him. I have no internet at home so he showed me a set of good reviews on his phone and their A+ on BBB. My wife has been wanting an alarm system so I took their $100 cash and agreed to let them install their "free" system.

System is installed, we paid the first $39.99 monitoring fee and they are wanting me to sign their paperwork to start our 5 year contract. I started to not feel good about this and looked them up for myself and found that they have bad reviews most everywhere but Google. I want to back out/save myself from this situation. If this is possible, how can I? Thank you for taking your time to help me with my bout of stupidity.

Comment: If you haven't signed a contract yet, you still have options.

Comment: Which state are you in?  What have you signed already?

Comment: @BenMiller, I am in Arizona.

Comment: @BenVoigt,  I had a recorded phone conversation with them in which I agreed to the system installation and also the monthly monitoring fee, however I have not signed any documents yet.

Comment: This is likely better suited for https://law.stackexchange.com/ as it's more about a legal obligation than a finance matter.

Comment: Has it already been [more than 3 days](https://www.azag.gov/consumer/threeday) since you agreed to this purchase?

Comment: @BobbyScon "Consumer issues or consumer protections" are explicitly [on-topic here](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @BenMiller, It was Thursday night, so it has only been two business days since.

Comment: @BenMiller, I was just reading the details in your link, Saturday is a business day so today is the 3rd day.

Comment: People might not like their service, but is it fair to call it a *scam*, especially as you've named the company?

Comment: According to reviews they do not provide service, continue taking money after cancellations, and harrass people who cancel their cards to prevent further charges. That sounds like a scam, so I feel it is fair to say I fell for a scam. However I only named them for reference, I can edit that out if it is felt the name does not add anything to the question.

Comment: @Lawrence Companies that sell door to door using high pressure sales tactics to lock people into difficult to cancel contracts that provide sub-standard service at high rates are scams in my book. What honest company would try to lock in a customer for five years of home alarm monitoring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [FTC has a "Cooling-Off Rule"](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0176-buyers-remorse-when-ftcs-cooling-rule-may-help) which gives you the right to cancel a sale made at your home for 3 business days after the sale.  According to the FTC website, Saturday is considered a business day, but Sunday is not.  By my count, if the sale was made on Thursday last week, then today (Monday) is the third business day, and you would need to cancel by midnight tonight.

In addition, the FTC requires home solicitation sales agents to inform you about your right to cancel.  They are required to give you two copies of a cancellation form.  I'm guessing that that didn't happen, or you would have known this already.  On that FTC article is a link for [reporting an FTC violation](https://www.ftccomplaintassistant.gov/#crnt&panel1-1).

If they didn't give you a cancellation form, I'd say your best bet is to call them up and cancel over the phone.  Perhaps in addition, you can send them a letter and see if you can get it in the mail today (ideally) or tomorrow.

Comment: You are correct, they did not inform me of any right to cancel or leave a cancellation form. As well as contacting the FTC should I reverse the monitoring fee charge? I imagine signing the paperwork would be an even bigger mistake also.

Comment: @LordMartlet It is likely too early to try to dispute the charge on your credit card, as the transaction is probably still pending.  In addition, at this point you have legitimately agreed to the charge, so disputing the charge is not appropriate yet.  I think you'll need to talk to them first, tell them you want to cancel, and see what they say before deciding what to do next.

Comment: Consider suggesting email as well so the OP has something concrete to show the FTC about his attempt to cancel within the cooling-off period.